# How to use DropZoneJS with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, dropzone.js

So far all examples I have seen so far have only a form with `file` element. I have a form with various fields and I can't assign `dropzone` class to `form` element. How can I set DropZone to a certain element instead of form? Check my Code:

*HTML*

```
<div id="myAwesomeDropzone" class="dropzone"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function initDropZone() {

    var baseUrl = "http://abc.dev";
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "file_name", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 2, // MB
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        url:baseUrl,
        accept: function(file, done) {
            alert(file);
        }
    };

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myAwesomeDropzone", { url: "/file/post"});
}
```

I am getting error:

**Uncaught Error: No URL provided.**

Comment: Probably because the `initDropZone()` function is called too late. Where are you calling the function?

Comment: in jquery's `ready()`

Comment: It might help if you can do a fiddle with the form itself, so we can see what you are doing